# ESP8266 send & recieve data without being in a network

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, esp8266

I want two NodeMCU ESP8266s to communicate to each other, but I don't want them in a network. I was thinking about the transmitter could broadcast packets all the time and the reciever could use the promiscuous mode to capture and read the packets. How to do this?

EDIT:
If this is not possible using the ESP8266 is there a chip which could do this(maybe a Raspberry PI and a NodeMCU or something).

Comment: If there is no network then there is no medium for broadcasting or receiving packets. Please explain what you’re trying to say or accomplish with “I don’t want them in a network”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you solely want to communicate among ESP8266 devices I suggest you give ESP-NOW a go.

[Espressif says](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/software/esp-now/overview)

> ESP-NOW is yet another protocol developed by Espressif, which enables
> multiple devices to communicate with one another without using Wi-Fi.
> The protocol is similar to the low-power 2.4GHz wireless connectivity
> that is often deployed in wireless mouses. So, the pairing between
> devices is needed prior to their communication. After the pairing is
> done, the connection is safe and peer-to-peer, with no handshake being
> required.

Here is a tutorial to get you started https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp-now-esp8266-nodemcu-arduino-ide/

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Do you know if there is a way to "broadcast" in a way that does not require knowing the target's MAC address?  Or maybe acquire a remote MAC address programatically?

Answer (score 1):

ESP is a Wi-Fi device. Wi-Fi needs a network in order to establish link-level connectivity.

But you can easily create an ad-hoc network between two nodes: start one in AP mode and another in client mode, connecting to that AP.

For example:

```
// "Server"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(IPAddress(192,168,4,1), IPAddress(192,168,4,1), IPAddress(255,255,255,0));
  WiFi.softAP("my_ssid", "password");
}
```

```
// "Client"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("my_ssid", "password");
}
```

Then use your favorite protocol (UDP, MQTT, ...) to broadcast messages ([UDP example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiSendReceiveUDPString)). You can broadcast with UDP by sending to IP 255.255.255.255.

Note that there is a dedicated site for Arduino-related questions: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK, if WiFi is not the solution to my problem. I really do not want to create networks. What chip I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: For ad-hoc WiFi ESP-NOW would probably be a better alternative -> my answer.

Comment: @HaroldTrotter WiFi is by far the easiest DIY solution and recommendations are off-topic on SO. But there are many wireless options for IoT, e.g. CC1101, NRF24, Si4432, RFM95 (LoRa), ZigBee, LTE-M, etc., which you can combine with a microcontroller like Arduino or Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Nordic nRF24 Series allow easy point to point wireless transfering.

https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/nRF24-series